# Can decorator wrap setter and getter in python?

Tags: python, python-decorators

I want to build various setter and getter. Fot not copy and paste the code, I thought something to solve it. Can decorator do it?

```
@property
def !!variable_name!!(self):
    return self.__!!variable_name!!

@!!variable_name!!.setter
def !!variable_name!!(self, input):
    self.__!!variable_name!! = input
```

Is it possible like macro in C?

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear why you would want to do something like this—create a property with setter that ignores its value argument—but the answer is **"Yes"**, you can do it by creating a function that returns a custom `property` object:

However you can't use `@` syntax to apply it. Instead you have to utilize it as shown:

```
def attribute_property(name, input_value):
    STORAGE_NAME = '_' + name

    @property
    def prop(self):
        return getattr(self, STORAGE_NAME)

    @prop.setter
    def prop(self, ignored):
        setattr(self, STORAGE_NAME, input_value)

    return prop

# EXAMPLE USAGE
class Person(object):
    name = attribute_property('name', 'Monty')

    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name  # ignores value of passed "name" argument!
        self.age = age

user = Person('Rodrigo', 42)
print('user.name: {!r}'.format(user.name))
print('user.age: {!r}'.format(user.age))
```

Output:

```
user.name: 'Monty'
user.age: 42
```

Comment: Minor typo: `self.name - name` should be `self.name = name`, right?

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer: Yes, that's possible using the descriptor protocol. For example you want to save variables with a leading underscore and access them without the leading underscore such a descriptor would work:

```
from six import string_types

class DescriptorSingleLeadingUnderscore(object):
    def __init__(self, attr, doc=""):
        if not isinstance(attr, string_types):
            # Not a string so take the documentation (if avaiable) and name
            # from the method.
            if attr.__doc__:
                doc = attr.__doc__
            attr = attr.__name__

        self.__doc__ = doc      # Set the documentation of the instance.
        self.attr = '_' + attr  # Add leading underscore to the attribute name

    def __get__(self, instance, owner=None):
        if instance is None:
            return self
        return getattr(instance, self.attr, None)

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        setattr(instance, self.attr, value)

    def __delete__(self, instance):
        delattr(instance, self.attr)

class X(object):
    someproperty = DescriptorSingleLeadingUnderscore('someproperty')
    someproperty1 = DescriptorSingleLeadingUnderscore('someproperty1')
    someproperty2 = DescriptorSingleLeadingUnderscore('someproperty2')
    someproperty3 = DescriptorSingleLeadingUnderscore('someproperty3')

    @DescriptorSingleLeadingUnderscore
    def it_also_works_as_decorator(self):
        pass # this code is never executed!
```

And a test case:

```
>>> x = X()

>>> x.someproperty = 100
>>> x.someproperty
100
>>> x._someproperty
100

>>> x.it_also_works_as_decorator = 100
>>> x.it_also_works_as_decorator
100
>>> x._it_also_works_as_decorator
100
```